# Is there a way to use the FindsBy annotation for WebDriverWait in the C# port of Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

So I started using this awesome feature:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div.location:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)")]
public IWebElement FirstLocationTile { get; set; }
```

But the problem is that it doesn't seem to work in my WebDriverWait code!

Concrete example, where I cannot re-use my FirstLocationTile. It insists on having a By.:

```
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(BaseTest.defaultSeleniumWait));
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("div.location:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)")));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't use C#, but I do know that many of the ExpectedConditions only accept `By` and not a `WebElement`.  However, in Java, waiting until an element is visible (not present, visible) is something you can do with a `WebElement`

Comment: I've tried FindsBy only to have errors on every web element. FindElement(By.Id/Xpath work. [Examples of PageFactory in java](http://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/wait-in-page-factory.html). Where is your PageFactory init elements line? Need more details on doesn't seem to work; exception, build failure, test failure. What kind of [wait](http://automationtricks.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/what-is-implicit-explicit-fluent-wait.html)?

Comment: couldn't you just use a By object instead? 

  public By FirstLocationTile => By.CssSelector("div.location:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)");

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(FirstLocationTile));

Answer (score 0):

If you use ExpectedConditions, you can only identify by locator, since ExpectedConditions only accepts locator as an argument.

However, ExpectedConditions is not the only argument you can use in wait.until(). You can use your element in a lambda expression instead.

^ This is true for C#, Python, and other languages.

[An example lambda expression use can be found in the C# documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm), and an example is below for what you are trying to achieve:

```
wait.Until(FirstLocationTile => FirstLocationTile.Displayed && FirstLocationTile.Enabled);
```

I used Displayed and Enabled as an example since there is no Visible property for elements [in the C# documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxWebElement.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own wait methods. Examples below:

```
    public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> ElementIsVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return (driver) =>
    {
        try
        {
            return element.Displayed;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // If element is null, stale or if it cannot be located
            return false;
        }
    };
}



public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementIsClickable(IWebElement element)
{
    return driver =>
    {
        return (element != null && element.Displayed && element.Enabled) ? element : null;
    };
}
```

These would be used similar to your standard wait.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
 wait.Until(ElementIsClickable(FirstLocationTile));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers nuget for it. Try it out

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("div.location:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)")))
```